# add CSS class on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, onchange

I Have two Select Box with the same class.I am trying to add a class on the change of select option.

HTML:

```
<select class="selectProduct" name="product_id[]">
  <option value="T-shirt">T-Shirt</option>
 </select>
<input type="text" name="sku[]" placeholder="Code" id ="sku" class="code" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" id ="qty" class="qty" />

 <select class="selectProduct" name="product_id[]" style="width:400px;">
  <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
 </select>
<input type="text" name="sku[]" placeholder="Code" id ="sku" class="code" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" id ="qty" class="qty" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.selectProduct', function(e) {
  var idSize = $(this).val();
  $(this).find(".code").addClass(idSize);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  `select` and input  is in same hierarchy so use `next` to get  input and add class .

`find` search inside the element you give so why your code is fail.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selectProduct', function(e) {
  var idSize = $(this).val();
  $(this).next(".code").addClass(idSize);
  $(this).next().next(".qty").addClass(idSize);
});
```

```css
.shirt {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.T-shirt {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectProduct" name="product_id[]">
  <option value="T-shirt">T-Shirt</option>
  <option value="shirt">shirt</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="sku[]" placeholder="Code" id="sku" class="code" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" id="qty" class="qty" />

<select class="selectProduct" name="product_id[]" style="width:400px;">
  <option value="T-shirt">T-Shirt</option>
  <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>

</select>
<input type="text" name="sku[]" placeholder="Code" id="sku" class="code" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" id="qty" class="qty" />
```

Comment: Shree@your code is working here great . but this is not working with my code

Comment: Shree@it's  Working Perfectly

Comment: Shree@if  i have add qty as same then

Comment: Shree@can you update answer for qty, That will save my whole day

Comment: shree@got it Thank you

Comment: shree@ can you help me to  make this write  this class    $('.code .'+idSize)

Comment: `$('.code .'+idSize)`  ? `.code` class is already present in your input ?

Answer (score 0):

The user can only change the value if the select box has more than one option, and it's easier to find the correct `.code` input to modify if we group the related inputs together.

Here's a revised version of your code that does as you suggest:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container-div');
container.addEventListener('change', addValAsClass);

function addValAsClass(event){

  const codeBox = event.target.closest(".input-group").querySelector(".code");
  codeBox.classList.add(event.target.value);
  
  console.log(`classList: ${codeBox.getAttribute('class')}`);
}
```

```css
div + div { margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-div">
  <div class="input-group">
    <select class="selectProduct">
      <option value="opt1">Opt 1</option>
      <option value="opt2">Opt 2</option>
    </select>
    <input placeholder="Code" class="code" />
    <input placeholder="Qty" class="qty" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <select class="selectProduct">
      <option value="optA">Opt A</option>
      <option value="optB">Opt B</option>
    </select>
    <input placeholder="Code" class="code" />
    <input placeholder="Qty" class="qty" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. i suggest wrapping the select + input into another div, to make finding easier.
2. your code might not work, because you have elements with non-unique **id** (`sku` and `qty`).

   ```
    <div>   <!-- wrapper start -->
        <select class="selectProduct" name="product_id[]">
        <option value="T-shirt">T-Shirt</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="sku[]" placeholder="Code" id="code" class="code" />
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" id="qty" class="qty" />
    <div>   <!-- wrapper end -->

    <div>   <!-- wrapper start -->
        <select class="selectProduct" name="product_id[]">
        <option value="T-shirt">T-Shirt</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="sku[]" placeholder="Code" id="code" class="code" />
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" id="qty" class="qty" />
    <div>   <!-- wrapper end -->
   ```

now you can find the next input by class in its parent container:

```
$(document).on('change', '.selectProduct', function(e) {
    var idSize = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find(".code").addClass(idSize); // <-- parent
})
```